# Page doesnt respond when many components are rendered and vue devtools is open

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

The component has a `<select>` tag, changing the value of which changes another component using `v-for`:

```
<template>
  <div class="game-board">
    <div class="minesweeper-grid"
      :style="{
         width: gridStyleSize,
         height: gridStyleSize,
         fontSize: difficulty.fontSize
      }"
    >
      <div class="cells">
         <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
        <Cell v-for="i in gridSize" :key="Math.random() + i"
            :style="{
               width: difficulty.cellSize + 'px',
               height: difficulty.cellSize + 'px',
            }"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Cell from './Cell.vue'
export default {
   name: 'Game Board',
   components: { Cell },
   props: {
      difficulty: {type: Object, required: true}, // changes when the value in select changes
   },
   computed: {
      gridSize() {
         return Math.pow(this.difficulty.size, 2)
      },
      gridStyleSize() {
         const { size, cellSize } = this.difficulty
         const borderWidth = 20
         return `${size * cellSize + borderWidth}px`
      }
   },
};
</script>
```

[Video preview](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/56202260/155890310-55826e80-bf91-4654-9227-499b9fe2aadb.mp4)

Experimentally, I found out with the help of `console.log()` that in each component `Cell.vue` calls `mounted()` lifecycle hook, but the page just doesn't respond, even the css hover on the element.

The page freezes **only** when I open vue-devtools. However, after a certain period of time, everything is rendered again, until the next change in `<select>`

**There is no such problem on vue 2**

Vue 3, Vue Devtools 6.0.12

Comment: Why do you use randomness in `:key="Math.random() + i"`?

Comment: Definitely sounds like a Dev Tools issue. Seen some strange performance issues with my own app when Dev Tools are opened just today. And yep, random key is really silly idea....

Comment: `I do not know why I added random keys` but you place it there so you thought "well just let's use random there"? the `:key` is used by vue to know which components can be reused and which ones have to replace/removed when the data is updated, and are used as a mapping from data to the DOM elements. So random is definitely nothing that should be used there.

Comment: Ok, I realized my mistake and removed random, but it still doesn't solve my problem